# I'm using the following code to convert YouTube videos into audio but getting error despite installing ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, youtube

This is the code I'm using and the error I'm getting:

Code:

from **future** import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl

ydl_opts = {
'format': 'bestaudio/best',
'postprocessors': [{
'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
'preferredquality': '192',
}],
}

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
ydl.download(['http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc'])

Error:

DownloadError: ERROR: ffprobe/avprobe and ffmpeg/avconv not found.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you should do is install ffmpeg, I recommend that to install it use chocolatey since if you install it with pip it will not work, here are the steps to install it https://chocolatey.org/install